# Append modal popup on body by angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am trying to show modal popup on body.I do not know how to do it?

I took script from the following links:

script for append content on body:

Guys please If you can not understand please ask me i will explain clearly..This is not duplicate.Please check and answer me.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I want to show popup on body not inside my-app

Comment: Chellappan:I tried but not working..Can you edit my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbxqfd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Chellapan: Are you there?

Comment: i am not sure how to do. try to learn custom elements in angular 6 which might help you!

Comment: Chellapan: Did you see the link??:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvnue8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal.service.ts

Comment: wait i will see

Comment: Chellapan:See this link also : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3q3npq?file=src/app/dialog/dialog.component.ts

Comment: Chellapan:After you saw the both links you can get idea.

Comment: Chellapan: You got any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177872/discussion-between-chellappan-and-apple-orange).

Comment: @AppleOrange, the link taht you gave doesn't have any thing in body of modal. I have anothegr working one here. just see if it helps you : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbxqfd

Answer (score 0):

[Check this code  here, this is a fork  of your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ot2mkx)

Before you can add components you have to define an anchor point to tell Angular where to insert components.
Your Service must have an exposed method to set the `ViewContainerRef` ’cause it’s not possible to inject the `ViewContainerRef` by using the service’s constructor due to it not being a Component, so we must use a setter method: `setRootViewContainer`.

```
export class AppComponent {
 name = 'from Angular'
 constructor(@Inject(Service) service, 
          @Inject(ViewContainerRef) viewContainerRef) {
        service.setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef)
        service.addDynamicComponent()
 }
```

addDynamicContainer adds the DynamicComponent to the DOM.

add dynamic component as an entryComponent to the module where you want to use it.

> The entryComponents will create a factory so that when the ComponentFactoryResolver is called we are able to create an instance of the component and add it to the DOM.

You might want to see the other tutorials for dynamically adding a modal:

[angular-dynamically-creating-components](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamically-creating-components-zie4h3)

Comment: thanks for pointing @nvoigt, i have updated my answer. will be careful next time